# FDT - Where is new Flash Project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, fdt

Up until this point I have been doing all of my coding in sublime text 2, and compiling with flash pro cs6. I have gotten pretty good with actionscript 3. I have been uing the mvc design pattern and used external libraries like admobs and electroserver. The real reason why I got fdt and wanted because I wanted to play a source file I downloaded in which the document class was mxml.

In every tutorial though I see them say, "oh just click new flash project". the problem is though that there is no choice "flash project" There is only actionscript project and fdt project or fla.

In flash ide I would use one .fla as a "shell" to publish from, and have another .fla with the assets that would be embedded in as3 from its swf. I'm sure that's not the way to set up files in fdt, but I dont know the right way to do it, or even the right way to start.

Maybe I am not finding the right page, but it seems that the documentation on the site is pretty weak. Are there good tutorials somewhere that will help me start compiling projects? thanks

A tutorial specifically for people transitioning from flash ide to fdt would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but from this IDE, you can't compile fla.
Instead of this, it provides another approach to build projects.
You have to start "new FDT Project", select base and set main class,
which must be compiled.
In result this approach more flexible and convinient.